# 2 sum functions from 2 different tables in 1 select statement. What's wrong?

Tags: sql

`I have 2 tables:incomes and sales and I want to show in query:

a) sum of incomes
b) sum of  sales
c) quantity of products now - difference between a-b

table 'incomes' has fields:Incomeid,ProductId,quant etc.
table 'sales' has fields:SalesId, IncomeId, ProductId, quant etc.

My SQL is:

```
select i.productId, sum(i.quant) as iq, sum(s.quant) as sq    
from income i,sales s  
where (i.incomeId=s.incomeId)  
group by i.productId
```

or

```
select i.productId, sum(i.quant) as iq, sum(s.quant) as sq  
from income  
left outer join  s on  (i.IncomeId=s.IncomeId)  
group by i.productId
```

My aim is result such as:

Id   sum(income)    sum(sales)    now

1     200         50          150
   2     150         20          130
   3     120         100         20

but I get wrong sum(income):
Id  sum(income)   sum(sales)  now

1     20000      50         19950
 2     27500      20         27480
 3     125000     100        12400

How can I write my SQL query to get this information?

For information, my database server is Interbase 2009.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
select incomecode,
       sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_income,
       sum(case when which = 'sales' then sum_amt else 0 end) as sum_sales,
       sum(case when which = 'income' then sum_amt else 0 end)
     - sum(case when which = 'sales' then sum_amt else 0 end) as diff_between
  from (select incomecode, sum(quant) as sum_amt, 'income' as which
          from income
         group by incomecode
        union all
        select incomecode, sum(quant), 'sales'
          from sales
         group by incomecode) x
group by incomecode
```

It appears that Interbase does not support inline views and, in your version, does not yet support case statements. In that case try the following:

Step 1: Create a view for income totals

```
create view income_vw
select incomecode, sum(quant) as sum_amt
  from income
 group by incomecode
```

Step 2: Create a view for sales totals

```
create view sales_vw
select incomecode, sum(quant) as sum_amt
  from sales
 group by incomecode
```

Step 3: Run the final select query which will use those 2 views

```
select coalesce(i.incomecode, s.incomecode) as incomecode,
       coalesce(i.sum_amt, 0) as sum_income,
       coalesce(s.sum_amt, 0) as sum_sales,
       coalesce(i.sum_amt, 0) - coalesce(s.sum_amt, 0) as diff_between
  from income_vw i
  full outer join sales_vw s
    on i.incomecode = s.incomecode
```

Comment: Brian DeMilia, thank you for quick answer but it would be right sql statement if my server were firebird 2.5, but I have Interbase 2009 and Derived tables ("SELECT FROM SELECT") is not supported in interbase 2009 server. Are there another ideas?

Comment: I don't see any way around using an inline view, if inline views aren't supported I would create a view and then use that view. See my edit

Comment: Brian DeMilia, what does mean bold words('income' and 'sales') in you sql? create view view_name as select incomecode, sum(quant) as sum_amt, ***'income'*** as which from income group by incomecode union all select incomecode, sum(quant),***'sales'*** from sales group by incomecode. table names or field names or what?

Comment: @Davidkoko in the view those are the values I'm using to distinguish between rows that come from the income table vs. the sales table. As you can see in the view those are being specified as literal values (that is why they are in single quotes)

Comment: Brian DeMilia,I'm very grateful for you many attempts but Interbase 2009 doesn't recognize select statement(step 2). On the 1st step it creates view, but on the 2nd step writes:expression evaluation not supported. Therefore, on Firebird 2.5 everything is ok. Do you know the other way out of a situation?! Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Davidkoko It looks like interbase did not begin supporting case statements until version 7.5 http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.interbase.sql/case-statement/1097535 the new method above (see edit) uses two views with very basic sql and the select basically just joins them together, hopefully that will work in IB

Comment: Brian DeMilia, server gives the same error. It creates views but didn't recodnize select statement.But everything works fine on the Firebird. There are no way out. It looks like I must recreate database file on the firebird 2.5 server. Thank you very much.